# Using anemone to search files and folders on my computer with ruby

Tags: ruby

When I view "My Documents" for instance in my browser (Default = chrome) I see a web page with links on denoting all of the folders and files within. Is there any way to get anemone to use this facility and essentially map my folders and files within a directory.

Thanks.

Alternative solutions to this problem using ruby code would be good too but I'm most familiar with anemone so would like to use it if possible.

I want to find all files with html in the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a web-crawler for searching files on local computer is a bit overkill. I guess that [`Dir.glob`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Dir.html#M000630) will do the job much faster.

```
html_files = Dir['**/*html*']
```